# How to keep order of long data when using ggplot based on a diff column?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting a unique type of plot where I show presence/absence of species with each point connected by a line to mimic another plot from a different study. The y-axis are species names and x-axis are sample dates. However, I need to maintain the order of species for other purposes such as ordering by family or preferably, ordering by collection dates.

Here is the dput of my data:

```
structure(list(Family = c("Halictidae", "Halictidae", "Halictidae", 
"Andrenidae", "Andrenidae", "Andrenidae"), Species = c("Agapostemon_sericea", 
"Agapostemon_texanus", "Agapostemon_virescens", "Andrena_commoda", 
"Andrena_crataegi", "Andrena_cressonii"), X21.Jun = c(0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), X22.Jun = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X23.Jun = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X24.Jun = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X30.Jun = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), X01.Jul = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X02.Jul = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X27.Jul = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X28.Jul = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X29.Jul = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X30.Jul = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X31.Jul = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X05.Aug = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X06.Aug = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X07.Aug = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X09.Aug = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Total = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", "3", "4", "9", "10"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the code for my plot after converting the Total column to a factor.

```
data$Total <- as.factor(data$Total)
# Convert data to long format
data <- data %>% pivot_longer(cols = "X21.Jun":"X09.Aug",
                              names_to = "Date",
                              values_to = "Counts") 

# Remove total collections of 0 so they don't get plotted
df2 <- data[data$Counts != 0,]

# Plot
ggplot(df2, aes(x=Date, y=Species, group=Species)) +
  geom_line(size=0.5,color='black') +
  geom_point(size=1.5) + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=5))
```

The problem is, I need the y-axis Species to be sorted by Total so that visually, we can see species with most collections at the top and least collected species at the bottom. I don't know how to include "Total" in the ggplot code so as to maintain the style of the plot (i.e., lines connecting each point by grouping Species) but keep order. Conversely, I also want to maintain order of Species by Family so I can plot a tree next to this figure with the complete dataset.

Comment: `data$Species <- forcats::fct_reorder(as.factor(data$Species), as.numeric(data$Total))`